# Is it safe to connect two 18650 batteries with different mAh capacities in series?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

Can I make a 2-cell 18650 battery pack connected in series with different mAh capacities and charge it without risk (with a balancer, of course), or does it carry the same risks as a different-voltages battery pack (connected in series too)?

Comment: No, no, not safe.

Comment: Overcharged battery may explode because of overheating.

Comment: why would you want to use batteries with different capacities?

Comment: @NoLiver92 Because I don't have batteries with same capacities

Comment: If your BMS is completely trustworthy, it will cut off charging when the smaller cell is full and discharging when it is empty, restricting the larger cell to the smaller capacity. It'll work but BMSes are more supposed to be a backup than a primary safety measure. (And if the BMS is really just a balancer, serious risk of fire.)

Comment: @user_1818839 thank you !

Comment: It's still not a good idea. But if you do it, you MUST be certain your BMS offers full cell-by-cell protection.

Comment: Absolutely not. Without BMS per cell, you will have a fiery explosion.

Comment: BMS is not intended to be a charge management device. It is supposed to cut off at a voltage just a tiny bit higher than the highest legitimate charge voltage. Basically, it makes no sense to do what you are proposing to do. I think the chances of an explosion or fire are still relatively remote, but it is not a good idea nonetheless.

Comment: @user_1818839 -- that's an answer, not a comment!  You should copy & paste it into an answer.

Comment: If you just need a 2 cell battery for testing something, fully charge each cell **individually** and monitor voltage on the lower capacity cell (or use a PCM to disconnect the battery when that cell reaches cutoff voltage). If you want to make a pack for general use then you should use two identical cells - including same part number, age, batch (if possible) and same measured capacity. Don't mix brands. Don't mix old and new cells.

Comment: @Tim. Maybe. But I worry it's a bit too positive about the prospects. Sure it'll work in a "Flight of the Phoenix" kind of way, if there is no other option, but that doesn't make it a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

When charging, the lower-capacity cell will reach its maximum voltage (say, 4.2 V) first, but the pack as a whole will not have reached its maximum voltage (8.4 V) yet, so constant-current charging will continue, and the lower-capacity cell will be overcharged.

So no, not safe.

Some (of the better) BMSes will stop the charging before something goes really wrong, but you don't want to rely on a BMS alone to prevent a cell from bursting into flames when you already know the battery pack is not OK.

Just don't do it. And if you must try, charge the battery pack outside, and stand well back.

Comment: thaank a lot ! I didn't know it was that much a bad idea !